# Meteor Build to android cordova error

Tags: cordova, meteor

Getting an error when running meteor run android-device.

Have been stuck on this problem for a few days now. With multiple searches around the web and stack overflow with solutions that have not worked.

I've post the error I'm getting followed by what I've tried.

Build error output

[image]

Have tried: 
Reinstalling linux mint 17.1 (rebecca)
reinstalling meteor
reinstalling java jdk 1.8.0_111
reinstalling android studio
reinstalling the android sdk

When adding the android platform to the meteor project (meteor add-platform android) not errors show up.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: The error message is suggesting one of your plugins needs to be updated - have you tried that?

Comment: @Mikkel I should've mentioned this is a newly built project. exactly what you get when you use meteor create ..... can you identify which plugin it may be?

Answer (score 1):

Tt is referencing cordova-plugin-splashscreen - presumably you have added the android or ios platform, and this must be an old version of the plugin it has loaded.

You can normally update meteor packages with the command

```
meteor update mdg:package
```

But for cordova packages you have to nominate a version with

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-splashscreen@x.x
```

Have a look to see what the latest version is

Comment: I've Tried updating all the packages, including the cordova ones, still no luck. I think i've got all my paths set right, I've got the JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME set in there. However still getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Mikkel's answer fixed the Cordava splash screen issue. But maybe the issue is with your Android Device.

Make sure you enable the Developer Mode for the device.

This helped me deploy my Meteor app to my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab A)...

[Failed to deploy to device while deploying cordova app to a connected device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993182/failed-to-deploy-to-device-while-deploying-cordova-app-to-a-connected-device)